# Error al conectar PHP con MySQL en DOCKER

Tags: docker, docker-compose

desde hace días estoy practicando con Docker y he encontrado un problema con el cual llevo un par de días atorado, espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo el siguiente archivo *docker-compose.yml* en el cual le cambie el puerto de mi maquina a MySQL por el *23306*

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  mariaDB:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: database_xadani
    volumes:
      - C:\xampp\mysql\data\docker-db:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: tienda
      MYSQL_USER: usuario
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "0123456789"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "0123456789"
    ports:
      - 23306:3306
  php:
    build: .
    container_name: php_container_xadani
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
    links:
      - mariaDB
```

Al momento de levantar mis servicios de PHP y MySQL lo hace sin problemas, de echo desde mi cliente de SQL me puedo conectar sin problema al puerto 23306.

Mi problema es cuando quiero conectarme desde mi contenedor de PHP a MySQL me lanza el siguiente error **Error #2002 Connection refused**, me conecto con la siguiente línea

*$mysqli = new mysqli("mariaDB:23306", "usuario", "0123456789", "tienda");*

También he intentado así y no he podido.

*$mysqli = new mysqli("mariaDB", "usuario", "0123456789", "tienda",23306);*

También modifique mi php.ini de mi contenedor, no estoy muy seguro si sirve de algo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTA:
Cuando no modifico el puerto por default de MySQLen el *docker-compose.yml* **3306** me puedo conectar con el cliente y con la aplicación que esta en el contenedor de PHP sin problema.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: tal como haces, no estas cambiando el puerto de msyql. Lo que estas haciendo es un forward de puertos, esto es para que tu localhost pueda conectar al host del docker. Pero desde un docker a otro, como tal, no estas cambiando el puerto.  Si realmente quieres cambiar el puerto de mysql, tienes que hacer un volume y, dentro de este, modificar el archivo de configuracion de mysql para indicarle un nuevo puerto. De todas formas, esto no es necesario. Realmente el contenedor no necesita cambiar de puerto (por eso hacer forwards)

Comment: en resumen, aunque hagas ese forward, desde el docker de php deberias seguir conectando al docker de mysql con el puerto 3306. y desde fuera, con el forward de puertos, con el 23306

Comment: Hola @Jakala muchas gracias si en efecto me estaba confundiendo sobre los puertos del contenedor y los de mi maquina